# Calling a function in Select Case terminates external Do While loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call either a SUB or Function in Case of a Select. Select works as it should when 'CreateNewEAF' is not called, incrementing 'numberOfCreatedFiles'. However, when 'CreateNewEAF' is called, Do While loop breakes after creating only one file. 'CreateNewEAF' opens old file and correct template, copies data from old file to new template and saves new file in new directory.

I tried switching to If...Then statement. Same result.

```
Private Sub FindPositionAndGrade()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim fileExtension As String
Dim oldEAF_FileName As String
Dim positionAndGrade As String
Dim numberOfCreatedFiles As Integer

fileExtension = "*.xlsx*"
numberOfCreatedFiles = 0
oldEAF_FileName = Dir(OldPathTxtBox.Text & "\" & fileExtension)

Do While oldEAF_FileName <> ""

    positionAndGrade = Split(oldEAF_FileName, " ", 3)(2)

   Select Case positionAndGrade

    Case "Software Engineer A.xlsx"
        numberOfCreatedFiles = numberOfCreatedFiles + 1
        CreateNewEAF oldEAF_FileName, positionAndGrade

    Case "Software Engineer B.xlsx"
        numberOfCreatedFiles = numberOfCreatedFiles + 1

    Case "Business Analyst A.xlsx"
        numberOfCreatedFiles = numberOfCreatedFiles + 1

    Case "Business Analyst B.xlsx"
        numberOfCreatedFiles = numberOfCreatedFiles + 1

    Case "Applications Consultant A.xlsx"
        numberOfCreatedFiles = numberOfCreatedFiles + 1

    Case "Applications Consultant B.xlsx"
        numberOfCreatedFiles = numberOfCreatedFiles + 1

   End Select

    oldEAF_FileName = Dir

Loop

MsgBox "Files created: " & vbNewLine & numberOfCreatedFiles

End Sub
```

I would like to open each file from directory provided in 'OldPathTxtBox.Text', and call sub/function in accordance with 'Select Case positionAndGrade'.

Body of the 'CreateNewEAF':

```
Function CreateNewEAF(oldEAF_FileName As String, positionAndGrade As String)

Dim templateEAF_FileName As String
Dim templateEAF_FileNameTemp As String
Dim templatePositionAndGrade As String
Dim fileExtension As String

fileExtension = "*.xlsx*"
templateEAF_FileName = Dir(TemplatePathTxtBox.Text & "\" & fileExtension)

Do
    templatePositionAndGrade = Split(templateEAF_FileName, " ", 2)(1)
    templateEAF_FileNameTemp = templateEAF_FileName
    templateEAF_FileName = Dir
Loop Until templatePositionAndGrade = positionAndGrade

Set workbookOriginal = Workbooks.Open(OldPathTxtBox.Text & "\" & oldEAF_FileName)
Set workbookTemplate = Workbooks.Open(TemplatePathTxtBox.Text & "\" & templateEAF_FileNameTemp)


workbookOriginal.Sheets("EAF").Range("C7:E8").Copy workbookTemplate.Sheets("EAF").Range("C7")
workbookOriginal.Sheets("EAF").Range("D9:E16").Copy workbookTemplate.Sheets("EAF").Range("D9")
workbookOriginal.Sheets("EAF").Range("C17:E24").Copy workbookTemplate.Sheets("EAF").Range("C17")
workbookOriginal.Sheets("EAF").Range("C28:E32").Copy workbookTemplate.Sheets("EAF").Range("C28")
workbookOriginal.Sheets("EAF").Range("C45:E46").Copy workbookTemplate.Sheets("EAF").Range("C45")

workbookTemplate.SaveCopyAs (NewPathTxtBox.Text & "\" & oldEAF_FileName)

workbookOriginal.Close SaveChanges:=False
workbookTemplate.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Function
```

Comment: Can you add the `CreateNewEAF` function code? Maybe there is an `End` which terminates the execution.

Comment: When you say **"Do While loop breaks"**, what actually happens? Is there an error thrown? or code just comes out of the loop?

Comment: Instead of cycling through all files in provided directory, do while gives up after finding first match for case statement., e.g.  Software Engineer A.xlsx, and then skips the rest.

Comment: You haven't got `oldEAF_FileName` declared as a public variable have you?

Comment: No, as a Dim in 'Private Sub FindPositionAndGrade()'. I tried declaring it as a public, with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateNewEAF oldEAF_FileName, positionAndGrade  will by default pass oldEAF_FileName by reference - so if your routine alters the value of that variable that new value will be returned to the calling routine. Change the definition of CreateNewEAF to pass ByValue or make sure you don't change the value within the subroutine

EDIT:
Now I've seen the CreateNewEAF I can see the problem. DIR is a system command and has its own memory. When you call DIR() without an argument it finds the next file according to the last argument it received. That means that the first time you go into CreateNewEAF the line

```
 templateEAF_FileName = Dir(TemplatePathTxtBox.Text & "\" & fileExtension)
```

resets your DIR to search for those files. And you loop through those files using DIR. So when you return to your calling routine and do

```
oldEAF_FileName = Dir
```

It gets either a template or nothing (depending on how much you've looped in the subroutine).  You'll need to switch to using the filesystemobject from the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Subroutine does modify given parameters. oldEAF_FileName and positionAndGrade are only used to find correct template, and save new file under the name of the old file in new directory.